# reference knitr chunk in R markdown

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, pandoc

I'm using knitr to embed R code within a markdown (.Rmd) file. I'm converting the file to a PDF file with Pandoc. The contents of my .Rmd file looks like this:

````
Report
========================================================

This is my report. Some analysis is included in LINK TO CHUNK NAMED MY.ANALYSIS HERE


```{r my.analysis, echo=FALSE}

summary(cars)

```
````

Where it says LINK TO CHUNK NAMED MY.ANALYSIS HERE, am I able provide a link to the code chunk named my.analysis in the outputted PDF?

I believe the OP asked a similar, but slightly different question here: [figure captions, references using knitr and markdown to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848137/figure-captions-references-using-knitr-and-markdown-to-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

````
Report
========================================================

This is my report. Some analysis is included in \href{http://stackoverflow.com/q/16445247/1000343}{LINK TO CHUNK NAMED MY.ANALYSIS HERE}


```{r my.analysis, echo=FALSE}

summary(cars)

```
````

And then covert the markdown file (not Rmd) to the PDF.

This also works using the [devel version of reports](https://github.com/trinker/reports):

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# set global chunk options
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)
library(reports); library(knitr); 
```
Report
========================================================

This is my report. Some analysis is included in `r HR("http://stackoverflow.com/q/16445247/1000343", "LINK TO CHUNK NAMED MY.ANALYSIS HERE")`


```{r my.analysis, echo=FALSE}

summary(cars)

```
````

You then convert the html file to pdf.

Comment: I now realize the question was to get an internal link.  This answer does not address that problem.

Comment: I thought maybe using `\ref{sec}` and `label{sec}` and converting the md to pdf would work but it does not.