# Figures captions and labels in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm new to Knitr. I'm trying to make a report using r chunks, and I can't figure out how to use captions and labels to reference the figure later on. 
Here's an example of what I would like to do:

````
---
title: "Plotting"

author: "xx"

date: '2015-08-10'

output: pdf_document
---
```{r figs, echo=FALSE, fig.width=7,fig.height=6,fig.cap="plotting example"}

    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    plot(1:10, col=2)
    plot(density(runif(100, 0.0, 1.0)))
    plot(runif(100, 0.0, 1.0),type="l")
```

in Figure \ref{fig:figs} we see examples of plotting in R.
````

I would like to have a caption "Plotting example", and have a label, so I can use Figure \ref{fig.label} in  the text. I have tried fig.cap and fig.lp, none of them works.
I would appreciate if if someone can help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Next time you post a question try to include if possible (like this case) a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), anyway the `fig.cap` chunk option is the right for you. See [here](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf) the complete guide to RMarkdown. Your problem is a matter of back reference but the solution may vary if the outupt is PDF or HTML. That's why the importance of a reproducible example.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can achieve this by including `fig_caption: yes` in the header:

````
---
title: "Plotting"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r figs, echo=FALSE, fig.width=7,fig.height=6,fig.cap="\\label{fig:figs}plotting example"}
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(1:10, col=2)
plot(density(runif(100, 0.0, 1.0)))
plot(runif(100, 0.0, 1.0),type="l")
```

in Figure \ref{fig:figs} we see examples of plotting in R.
````

[image: click here to see a screenshot]

Note that the figure caption label should be included in the caption with a double backslash, as shown above.

Comment: This didn't work for me, possibly because I'm using VS 2017  rather than RStudio. If you have the same issue as me follow this link for [an elegant  manual solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28895606/5147442)

Comment: Worked for me with out stating `fig_caption: yes`.

Comment: With html_document, the "Figure 1:" part is not written to the html file.

Comment: I'm wondering how the `Figure 1:` part can be written, just like @user2955884

Comment: what if I would like to add subtitle for each plot like "a", "b", "c" ?

Answer (score 0):

I also need to caption multiple figures in the same chunk, but this doesn't work. Am I missing something?
I also found a solution of typing:

```
fig.cap = c("caption1","caption2")
```

Hope that helps